# What happens in Xamarin when Forms.Init gets called and the function is already running in another thread?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm thinking about how to reduce the cost of loading Forms.Init during the start of my app. 
There's some work my app does that I can already do without access to Xamari.Forms. I'm thinking about loading Forms.Init in parallel in another thread.
In case that thread isn't yet finished and I already need Xamari.Forms, I'm not sure what my option are at handling the event.

What happens in Xamarin when Forms.Init gets called and the function is already running in another thread? Or are there otherwise best practices of dealing with loading Forms.Init in parallel to other work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Forms.Init()` calls the private `SetupInit()` which runs platform dependent code ranging from getting an Android Context, registering renderers, adding log listeners, etc...

```
Assembly callingAssembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly ();
SetupInit (activity, callingAssembly);
```

There are no callbacks or events tried to the competition of `Init` other then its synchronous completion, but there is a boolean flag that can be checked:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.IsInitialized
```

**But**, depending upon platform, this flag can be set at the beginning of the method or at the end and also note there is no `lock` on setting this flag (which would cause a performance hit).

So, if the other code you need to run can be done completely without Forms, yes, you could do run this in parallel.

Your `Application` subclass and its `LoadApplication` step, of course, should not be done until `Init()` is finished.

re: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms